# How to call Groovy or Scala UDF to update Oracle, using Java?

Tags: java, oracle, scala, groovy, udf

I have a JDBC connection to an Oracle DB. I also have some function f(x) written in Groovy or Scala. For example, f(x) simply returns 2x.

Now my question is: how should I call this f(x) in my Java code, to apply f(x) to all values in a column, and update this column to 2x in the above example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [withColumn](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html) api to update the column's values.

If your function is returning a constant [lit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) should be a good choice. You can find a lot of [functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) too.

You can use `udf` function too as

```
def func = udf((column: Int)=> 2*column)
dataframe.withColumn("column1", func(dataframe("column1")))
```

but `udf` function would need serialization and deserialization column values. So if other functions should be preferred.

Comment: Thank you! But this is using Spark, right? My problem is that the majority of my code is in Java. I'm using JDBC to connect to Oracle, and hope to be able to call functions written in other languages such as Groovy/Scala etc.

Comment: Yes thats right. The solution is for spark. but you can use udf for other cases too as udf was originally created for hive.